# NumberPicker OnValueChangeListener not called when setValue

Tags: android, testing, listener, automated-tests, numberpicker

I am writing automated tests and I want to test that the onValuChangeListener is being called and is doing what is expected.

I run on the UI thread.

```
picker.setValue(myIndex);
```

But unfortunately the listener method is not called. 
The index is a valid index.
Yes I am adding the listener and yes the method is called when I run/debug the app so it is setup properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not something thats possible with NumberPicker. If you take a look at the source you will see the following:

```
public void setValue(int value) {
    setValueInternal(value, false);
}
```

As you can see setValueInternal has `int value` and a `boolean notify` arguments. When `notify` is true, the method calls `NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener` interface with any changes. Since its false it will never notify your listener. You will need to handle the change yourself.